# jquery object returns undefined in second `.forEach()`

Tags: jquery

hello so i want to display the json data ( question and his answers ).i use `.forEach()` to loop throw questions to get me the question and another `.forEach()` to loop throw his answers, but only shows the question and returning  the answers as `undefined` .
i tested if i get all data correctly ,and it is.

it seems to be a fail when displaying the answers objects.

```
res.questions.forEach((el) => {
    $('#additional').before($('<section>\
    <h1 class="f-title">'+ el.question +'</h1>\
    <h3 class="f-subtitle">'+ el.commentary +'</h3>\
    <div class="container1">'
    +el.answers.forEach((i) => {
        '<input type="button" class="buttn" value="'+i.answer+'"/>'
     })+'</div>\
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />\
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />\
</section>'));

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently  you cannot append object then loop inside it.that why `.forEach()`or`map()`  show up as `undefined` because it wasn't recognized inside `.before()`. so i had to use it before appending objects
,therefore when the first `.foreach()` finish the second one reaches its objects and loop throw.

```
res.questions.forEach((el) => {
                    $('#additional').before('<section id="'+el.id+'">\
                    <h1 class="f-title">'+ el.question +'</h1>\
                    <h3 class="f-subtitle">'+ el.commentary +'</h3>\
                    <div class="container1">\
                    </div>\
                    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />\
                    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />\
                    </section>')
                });
                res.questions.forEach((el) => {
                    el.answers.forEach((i) => {
                        $("#dynamic_frm").find("section#"+el.id+"> .container1").append('\
                        <input type="button" class="buttn" value="'+i.answer+'" />'
                        )})
                })
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach()` doesn't return anything, so you're concatenating `undefined` into your HTML.

You can use `.map()` to return an array of all the `<input>` strings, and `.join()` to concatenate them together into a single string.

```
res.questions.forEach((el) => {
    $('#additional').before($('<section>\
    <h1 class="f-title">'+ el.question +'</h1>\
    <h3 class="f-subtitle">'+ el.commentary +'</h3>\
    <div class="container1">'
    +el.answers.map((i) => {
        '<input type="button" class="buttn" value="'+i.answer+'"/>'
     }).join("")+'</div>\
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />\
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />\
</section>'));

});
```

Comment: thanks for the replay @Barmar, actually i want to loop throw answers array that contains objects and display it as separated objects foreach input buttons elements.

Comment: Isn't that what this does? `map()` loops through the array of objects, and returns an array of the results of the function. `join()` combines them into a single string.

Comment: yes  u r right, but it didn't work  because it couldn't loop throw the array inside `.before()`(and this is what's wrong).so i did this ,it'not pretty but works.